# extract URL until .com , .org etc

Tags: python, regex

Below is my regex to extract URL

```
url_extractor  re.compile(r'((?:www\.|http:|https:)[^\s]+)', re.IGNORECASE)
mystring = """https://myname.abc.comsomename: """
```

The regex above extracts URL and any characters present after `.com`, in this case `somename`: `https://myname.abc.comsomename`.

I want to extract only until `.com` or `.org` (inclusive) if present. If URL does not end with `.com` or `.org` I would like to extract until whitespace.

So in the above example, the expected result `https://myname.abc.com`.

if the URL is `https://myname.abc.xyz somename`, expected result is
`https://myname.abc.xyx`.

How do I modify my regex above?

Comment: Why not use `urlparse`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
re.compile(r'(?:www\.|https?:)\S*?(?:\.(?:com|org)|(?=\s)|$)', re.IGNORECASE)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/RMNPY8/3)

**Details**

- `(?:www\.|https?:)` - `www.` or `http:` or `https:`
- `\S*?` - 0 or more non-whitespace chars, as few as possible
- `(?:\.(?:com|org)|(?=\s)|$)` - either `.` and then either `com` or `org`, or a location immediately followed with a whitespace, or end of string.

[Python demo](https://ideone.com/6w0qds):

```
import re
text = r'somename https://myname.abc.comsomename: if the URL is https://myname.abc.xyz somename..'
rx = re.compile(r'(?:www\.|https?:)\S*?(?:\.(?:com|org)|(?=\s)|$)', re.IGNORECASE)
print ( rx.findall(text) )
# => ['https://myname.abc.com', 'https://myname.abc.xyz']
```